# My POST request is returning a 404 not found but my GET request on the same route works

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I'm currently following along https://youtu.be/Ud5xKCYQTjM but in TypeScript, my GET request works

```
GET http://localhost:48080/users

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 2
ETag: W/"2-l9Fw4VUO7kr8CvBlt4zaMCqXZ0w"
Date: Thu, 28 Jul 2022 13:14:52 GMT
Connection: close

[]
```

while my POST request fails

```
POST http://localhost:48080/users Content-Type: application/json

{
"name": "Kyle", "password": "password"
}

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
X-Powered-By: Express
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 180
Date: Thu, 28 Jul 2022 13:15:09 GMT
Connection: close

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot POST /users%20Content-Type:%20application/json</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

I am unsure why it returns a 404 not found when the route exists? I've tried removing 'async' in my server.ts file in regards to the post request, as at the start of the guide, he did not use 'async' but it did not work. Could CORS be an issue? but I'm sending requests within the same origin.

server.ts

```
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import { Request } from "express-serve-static-core";
import { ParsedQs } from "qs";
// const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

/* Set up server app */
const app = express();
// const port: number = +(process.env.PORT || 48080);
const port: number = 48080;

const users: { name: string; password: string; }[] = []

app.get('/users', (req, res) => {
  res.json(users)
})

app.post('/users', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = { name: req.body.name, password: req.body.password }
    users.push(user)
    res.status(201).send()
  } catch {
    res.status(500).send()
  }
})

app.post('/users/login', async (req, res) => {
  const user = users.find(user => user.name === req.body.name)
  if (user == null) {
    return res.status(400).send('Cannot find user')
  }
  try {
    if(userAuthenticate(req, user)) {
      res.send('Success')
    } else {
      res.send('Not Allowed')
    }
  } catch {
    res.status(500).send()
  }
})

/* Listen for incoming connections */
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`API listening on port ${port}.`);
});

/* Enable CORS */
app.use(cors({
    origin: ["http://localhost:3000", "http://localhost:48080"],
    credentials: true,
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200
}));

function userAuthenticate(req: Request<{}, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>, user: { name: string; password: string; }) {
    return req.body.password == user.password;
}
```

Comment: @Normal — Express v4 doesn't care what the return value of a function is. It is perfectly fine to use an `async` function. [There's even an example in the docs](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html). Express just won't do anything with the promise it returns. "Not supporting async functions" just means "You still need to explicitly call `next()` for your middleware".

Comment: @Quentin, yes that's correct

Comment: Currently using "express": "^4.18.1", I'll remove the async functions then. Thanks

Comment: @JoeyLeo — Using `async` is pointless (because the functions don't use `await`) but harmless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the error message:

> Cannot POST /users%20Content-Type:%20application/json

Now look at your command line:

> POST http://localhost:48080/users Content-Type: application/json

The tool you are using to make the HTTP request is treating `Content-Type: application/json` as **part of the path** and not as a request header.

You need to read the documentation for your `POST` command line tool and figure out how to make it an HTTP header.

Comment: This has gone over my head thanks! It's definitely the right step but now I'm obtaining a 500 internal server error. Is there something wrong with the syntax of my request?

Comment: "500 internal server error" just means *something has gone wrong on the server*. You need to look at your server looks to figure out what.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was able to find out that my current express setup does not have a `req.body`, so I needed a middleware in order to read req.body. I used `app.use(express.json())` to solve my problem.